# Accessing a textbook properties from a different application

Tags: wcf, remoting

I am in the early stages of writing an automation tool that needs to access the properties of a textbox that is in an entirely different application. Is there a way I can accomplish this using Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). Ideally I would like to be able to access any object from this tool.